# Datatables not defined when rendered through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using datatables to in a web page as follows:

```
<script src="js/admin/vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/admin/vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTable').DataTable({
      "destroy": true,
    });
});
</script>
```

When I load this webpage normally the datatables are rendered without any issues. However, when I load this page using ajax, I get an error as Datatables is not defined.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST'
  url:'http://example.com',
  success: function(res) {
    response.innerHTML = res;
    var scripts = response.querySelectorAll('script');
    for (i = 0; i <= scripts.length; i++) {
        // there is additional logic defined here
        $('body').append(scripts[i]);
    }
  }
})
```

I could see the datatables scripts appended to the document. However, inline javascript doesn't seem to execute properly. Please help.

Comment: Please read this document, i think it is regarding to retrive options https://datatables.net/reference/option/retrieve

Comment: I tried to set retrieve to false as well as true, in either case it doesn't work